# Is there a way to run `rake routes > doc/routes.txt` when a git commit contains routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, githooks

I like to keep the full set of routes in our Rails app in a text file to allow for east Diff's between releases (allows for a sanity check to see if we've blown away a route commonly bookmarked or perhaps used in a marketing email)

Running `rake routes > doc/routes.txt` makes this easy, but it is still an extra step developers have to take.

Does anyone have an idea of how to integrate this into git so that the text file is automatically updated whenever routes.rb is updated?

Comment: If you are using rails 4.0 or higher, rails provides the routes info  at `rails/info/routes` on dev env. Might be a good idea to use this info to do the sanity check rather than a separately created `doc/routes.txt`. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8186754097e0cc54a8853f2a5c0d2b3fbf4ae059 & https://github.com/schneems/sextant for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a write a [Git Hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).